# Check for existence of a process in c++ using a thread

Tags: c++, c, process, pthreads

I am trying to check the existence of a process in c++ using a thread.
I initially tested without having any thread and let the main check for existance.
It worked.
But suddenly when I put that part of the code inside a thread the its does not work.
I am puzzled to see it not working.
Could anybody please tell me why the part of the code is not working when it comes to using it in a thread.

My initial test program for existance of a process:
Compiled as below: `CC protest2.cc -o nothr`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

struct stat sts;
string f=string("/proc/")+argv[1];
while(!(stat(f.c_str(), &sts) == -1 && errno == ENOENT))
{
cout<<"process exists"<<endl;
sleep(1);
}
cout<<"process Does not exist"<<endl;
return 0;

}
```

A small process which runs for some secs and then exits.

```
int main() {
sleep(5);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
sleep(2);
}
}
```

My second test program for existance of a process using a thread(this does not work):
Compiled as below: `CC protest.cc -o thr`

```
extern "C" void *run(void *str){

struct stat sts;
while(!(stat((char *)str, &sts) == -1 && errno == ENOENT))
{
cout<<"process exists"<<endl;
sleep(1);
}
return NULL;

}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
string f=string("/proc/")+argv[1];

pthread_t pid;
int res=pthread_create(&pid,NULL,run,(void *)f.c_str());
pthread_join(pid,NULL);
cout<<f<<endl;
cout<<"process Does not exist"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

**Output when there is no thread:**

```
> ./a.out &
[1] 10128
> ./nothr 10128
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process Does not exist
[1]  + Done                          ./a.out
>
```

**Output when there is thread:**

```
> ./thr 10458
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
process exists
^C
```

It goes on untill i press CTRL+C.

Comment: In your thread functions `while` loop condition you're repeatedly calling `!(stat((char *)str, &sts) == -1` with the same parameters. Thus it loops forever.

Comment: But the while loop should exit once the process does not exist. this is what the condition in the while loop does.

Comment: And the same while condition is present in the case when there is no thread and as expected there the while exits as soon as the process exits. But out of curiousity why a down vote here?

Comment: Probably because you seem to have made no attempt to debug your problem.  For instance, you could have couted/printf'd the string passed into your thread function to ensure that it is correct.

Comment: You could have split up the check into two lines, with separate temp bools for results, to see which fails/succeeds.

Comment: You could have run it under a debugger with a break on the compare line and checked values.

Comment: NO - I did not downvote your question, but I could easily have done so for posting your code on SO before performing some obvious and trivial debugging steps.

Comment: @martin, I checked by printing the string (process id) inside the thread function and also inisde the while loop. It gives the correct pid.

Answer (score 1):

Very very technically, the valid lifetime of `f.c_str()` (in your threaded code sample) is purely for the duration of the `pthread_create` call. So it is possible at the time the thread calls `stat`, the contents of the address passed have changed sufficiently to cause you to get an error other than `ENOENT`. which will fail your test and you'll loop forever.

In passing, using `kill(pid, 0)` is a much more portable and lightweight way of testing for the existence of a process.

Comment: I checked by printing the string inside the thread and it shows the correct process id.

Comment: that loop will continue until stat returns -1 and errno is set to ENOENT. Clearly it isn't. so either you're looking at the wrong pid or the code isn't as posted.